# Selecting from a Database based on a list of unique pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql

For Example if I am given the following table

```
Id        Key             Value

 1          A             Alpha
 2          B             Alpha
 3          A             Charlie
```

And I took the input {(A, Charlie) and (B, Alpha)} and I asked to return all the IDs I would want it to return 2 and 3 but NOT 1.

What is the best way to do this? Can I combine it all into one query, (for speed) or would I have to run a repeat query for each value pair I received.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  How are the inputs stored, in variables or something else?  How are you planning on calling the query?

Comment: I am a little confused at RDBMS but I am using postgre and accessing the database with java using hibernate.

Comment: Note, it's Postgres not Postgre

Comment: Tomato Tomato.... that does not work as well written down

Comment: @Landister Tomat, Tomato, more like :-P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Postgresql has the most elegant solution:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   ("Key", "Value") IN (('B', 'Alpha'), ('A', 'Charlie'));
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9cdb4/6)

In SQL-SERVER 2008 and onward you can use `VALUES` to build your tuples:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   VALUES
                ('B', 'Alpha'),
                ('A', 'Charlie')
        ) v (Key, Value)
            ON v.Key = T.Key
            AND v.Value = T.Value
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7eff9/3)

Or for a procedure you could create a key-value pair type and pass this as a parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE KeyValuePair AS TABLE ([Key] VARCHAR(1), [Value] VARCHAR(7));

DECLARE @T AS KeyValuePair
INSERT @T 
VALUES
    ('B', 'Alpha'),
    ('A', 'Charlie')


SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN @T v
            ON v.[Key] = T.[Key]
            AND v.Value = T.Value;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed9e6/7)

For MySQL I think you may have to just build this using `AND/OR`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   (`Key` = 'A' AND `Value` = 'Charlie')
OR      (`Key` = 'B' AND `Value` = 'Alpha')
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b14/6)

My Knowledge of other DBMS is limited, so if it is not one of the above sorry I can't be of more help.

**EDIT (With the help of [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name))**

The PostgreSQL syntax also works for [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ac8f/1) (and I think DB2)

Comment: The PostgreSQL syntax also works for Oracle (and I think DB2)